# What is the cause of soot in the plume of the Raptor engine?

Tags: engines, spacex-starship, chemistry, combustion, raptor

Though the Raptor engine burns quite clean, it was clear from some early test flights that it did produce some visible soot:

[image: SN10 launching with a brown plume]

There have been differing explanations for the exact cause of/source of this soot. [Some](https://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/comments/x9kmtm/starship_development_thread_37/ipjsnpa/) have said that the soot is produced because combustion in the engine is slightly fuel rich (not stoichiometric). [Others](https://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/comments/1073h72/starship_development_thread_41/j4ffc7r/) say that the overall mixture ratio cannot account for what we see, and that the soot is instead a direct result of film cooling at the throat.

**Which is correct, or are neither?**

For a possible clue that I haven't yet found a good explanation for, take a look at the [SN10 livestream](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ODY6JWzS8WU) and note how the soot doesn't seem to be expelled at a constant rate. There are a few seconds of heavy soot, followed by a few seconds of a very clean burn. If film cooling (which is, I believe, a constant thing) was causing the soot, would this happen?

Comment: I assume that dynamic throttling could affect both the rate of both soot production and film ablation, so I don't think it's a definitive differentiator by itself.